# Hibernate Envers for EclipseLink (Entity Auditing)

Tags: java, eclipselink, audit

I have been looking at Hibernate Envers for entity auditing.  I'm using EclipseLink but I'd like something similar.

I've seen some implementations that involve creating a SessionCustomizer to handle some of the persistence of auditing data.  I'd really like something like Hibernate where I can simply annotate the entity and have the same effect.

Comment: Is there any other solution today? did any one use Javers / audi4j? would it fit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, EclipseLink doesn't have a feature which covers auditing out-of-the-box.

We use a [SessionEventListener](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Sessions_%28ELUG%29#Session_Event_Manager_Events) to intercept a flush or commit and use the calculated changeset for inserting the auditing data into audit tables.

Comment: MRalwasser, can you share more about how to get/calculate changeset? thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is support for auditing of entities in EclipseLink. They call it  **History**.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History

Comment: History is a good feature. But it cannot work well with batch write. Batch write is disabled after you applied history policy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848686/eclipselink-batch-write-is-disabled-when-use-history-policy-or-descriptoreventad